# Firesotre query with null variable

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to query a collection using multiple "where" like the example below

```
const queryRef = citiesRef
  .where('state',   '==', v1)
  .where('city',    '==', v2)
  .where('address', '==', v3);
```

The question is: how to check if v1, v2 or v3 ... is null so that i can remove it from the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the [`where()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Query#where) method returns a `Query`, you can check for each value as follows:

```
let queryRef = citiesRef;
if (v1 !== null) {
  queryRef = queryRef.where('state',   '==', v1);
}
if (v2 !== null) {
  queryRef = queryRef.where('city',   '==', v2);
}
// ...
```